# How to configure Connection String in <appSettings> </appSettings> tab for ASP.Net MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, connection-string

Net MVC3 application using VS2010 which allows to configure Database ConnectionString in   tab as below

How ever my Hosting Server is not supporting it and force me to put connection string inside   tab as below

How can i use ConnectionString of  for MVC 3 Entity Framework Code First Model based applicaiton. Is it possible to put connection string inside  tab and if its possible then how can i use it in my ASP.Net MVC3 Entity Framework Code First Model ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly after doing too much R&D i got success to deploy my MVC3 application on shared hosting server with Database connection properly working without any problem.I try to deploy my MVC3 application with Entity Framework Code First Model on shared hosting server but it don't allow me as we do not have database creation and drop permission on shared hosting server. I try too much it should allow me to host my application with Entity Framework Code First but i can't do id due to limited access permissions on shared hosting database server. Finaly i need to find some alternative and i try to deploy my MVC3 application with Entity Framework Database First Model. It will generate edmx file for your model class but you can update it to poco class using T4 template of ADO.Net DBContext Code Generator. Please watch Julie Lerman's below video to get more idea about it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg702905

Once you develop your application as shown in above video, Change your web.config settings with your hosting server database value in Connection string and publish your application and upload it on your FTP Server. You found it work without any problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use the connectionStrings section, not appSettings

```
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="MyApp" connectionString="DataSource=|DataDirectory|MyApp.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
    </connectionString>
```

This assumes your DbContext class is also called MyApp.  You need to change MyApp in the connection string above to match the name of your DbContext class.

That connection string also assumes you have an App_Data folder in your project.  If you do not, you can add it by right clicking your web project, choosing Add, Asp.Net Folder, then App_Data.

If all of that is set up properly, when you run your app and hit a page that uses the DbContext, it will automatically generate the sdf file in the App_Data folder.  You can also use a normal SQL Server connection string, but CE is a nice way to make sure everything is working the way you would like it to when you're getting started.

Comment: Hi Nathan, If i use connectionString as you mention then its work fine on my local machine but its not working on my Web Server, Its giving me error of invalid provider name. When i ask to Hosting Provider they suggest me to configure connection string in <appSettings> <add key="connectionstring" value="ConnectionString Without ProviderName"> </appSettings> tag inside web.config without provider name. Do you have any idea how to configure connection string inside <appSettings> tag of web.config file and use it for MVC3 Entity Framework Code First Model based Application ?

Comment: What type of storage are you using on your server?  Is it a real SQL server?  SqlCE?  MySQL?  I don't believe you can use the appSettings section to store a connection string used by the Entity Framework.

Comment: It is SQL Server on my shared web hosting server. I found one option of Database.DefaultConnectionFactory in which we can pass connection string stored in <appSettings>. But i don't have any idea how to configure it in Global.asax. We can directly use it on  controller page where we need to fire query in below manner Database.DefaultConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnctionString"].ToString()); If you have any idea then let me know.

Comment: Nathan there must be some way to deploy MVC application in shared hosting environment where we have too much restrictions with database drop and creation access permission. if anyone else who can help me please give your input for this question as its practicle problem and it might help to others in future

Comment: I still can't believe that something with your hosting provider prevents you from setting up a connection string in the proper location in your .config file.  Can you post your connection string with dummy text for the username/password?  Post the whole < add > tag including the provider.  Also, there is a context menu item on your web project called "Add Deployable Dependencies" that will help you deploy items to a shared environment that may be in the GAC on your computer (MVC dlls for example).

Comment: Yas my hosting provider might not have any site till now hosted with MVC3. I am the first who are hosting MVC3 Entity Framework Code First Model site on the hosting server. My Connection string is <connectionStrings> <add name="dbContextClass"
         connectionString="Data Source=DBServerIP;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=DBUserName;Password=DBPassword"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/> </connectionStrings>